# Override C++ method from multiply inherited templated base class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, multiple-inheritance

The enclosed code is a trimmed-down example of something I'm encountering.

First, here's an even more simplified version that manages to compile:

```
#include <string>

template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}

    virtual size_t Size (void) const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public virtual Base<T>
{
public:
    Derived() {}
    virtual ~Derived() {}

    virtual size_t Size (void) const override { return 0; }
};

class Impl : public virtual Derived<std::string>,
    public virtual Base<char const *>
{
public:
    Impl() {}
    virtual ~Impl() {}

    using Base<char const *>::Size;
    virtual size_t Size() const override { return 1; }
};

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Impl oImpl;
}
```

The issue is being able to implement `Base<std::string>::Size()` as well as `Base<char const *>::Size()`.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770116) was instrumental in reaching this stage. (The `using` statement was key.)

However, the problem is that, in the real code, I'm not merely returning a `size_t`, but an instance of a nested class.

```
#include <string>

template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}

    class Contained
    {
    public:
        Contained();
        virtual ~Contained();
    };
    virtual Contained begin (void) const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public virtual Base<T>
{
public:
    Derived() {}
    virtual ~Derived() {}

    virtual typename Base<T>::Contained begin (void) const override
        { return typename Base<T>::Contained(); }
};

class Impl : public virtual Derived<std::string>,
    public virtual Base<char const *>
{
public:
    Impl() {}
    virtual ~Impl() {}

    using Base<char const *>::begin;
    virtual typename Base<char const *>::Contained begin() const override
        { return typename Base<char const *>::Contained(); }
    /* virtual typename Base<char const *>::Contained Base<char const *>::begin() const override
        { return typename Base<char const *>::Contained(); } */
};

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Impl oImpl;
}
```

Somehow, g++/clang++ thinks this is a redefinition of `Base<std::string>::Size`, not `Base<char const *>::Size` – it complains of an invalid covariant type. So the `using` statement that worked so well in the first code sample is ineffective here.

If I try to fully qualify the name, i.e. the commented-out section, g++ gives me `cannot define member function 'Base<const char*>::Size' within 'Impl'` (without saying why), and  clang++ gives me `non-friend class member 'Size' cannot have a qualified name` (which I don't understand at all).

Does anyone know how to override methods from different instances of the same templated base class?

If anyone's interested, `Base` is a generic "enumerable" class, and I'm trying to create a class that has both a mutable interface (i.e. derived from `Base<std::string>`) and a read-only interface (i.e. derived from `Base<char const *>`) that doesn't leak how the string data is stored internally. (In general, I'm trying to implement C#-style enumerable interfaces in C++, e.g. so a client doesn't have to know that the underlying class is based on a list, vector, set, map, or whatever, only that its contained values can be enumerated through a non-specific interface class...implying that `Contained` is actually an iterator class).

Comment: It looks like what you want is *specialization* rather than inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is essentially this:

```
struct A { 
    virtual int foo() { return 0;} 
};

struct B { 
    virtual double foo() { return 0;} 
};

struct C : A, B {
    int foo() override { return 42; }
    double foo() override { return 3.14; }
};
```

Oops! You can't do that. Each overrider of foo() in C overrides all foo() (same argument list, any return type) in all base classes. No fiddling with `using` changes that.

What you need is essentially rename foo such that C inherits two functions of different names. Stroustrup proposes a technique of doing exactly that (in D&E I think but don't quote me on that).

```
struct A { 
    virtual int foo() { return 0;} 
};
 
struct B { 
    virtual double foo() { return 0;} 
};
 
struct AA : A {
   virtual int foo1() { return 1; }
   // Essentially rename foo to foo1
   int foo() override { return foo1(); }
};
 
struct BB : B {
   virtual double foo2() { return 1; }
   // Essentially rename foo to foo2
   double foo() override { return foo2(); }
};
 
struct C : AA, BB {
    int foo1() override { return 42; }
    double foo2() override { return 3.14; }
};
```

Now C still has two functions named `foo()` but they are frozen. From this point on, you manipulate only foo1 and foo2. Of course you can still call foo() via A and B, and these will call the correct version.

So yes, C::foo is essentially a forbidden name. That's the price.

Comment: But I *do* want `Base<std::string>::Contained` and `Base<char const *>::Contained` to be two completely different, unrelated classes, just as `std::vector<std::string>::iterator` and `std::vector<char const *>::iterator` are two completely different, unrelated classes.

Comment: Then you cannot override `begin()` in `Impl` because the overrider must override both versions. I'm sorry it looks like I misunderstood your problem. I will try to update my answer, but it could take a while.

Comment: @n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m : I need implementations for both `begin()` methods in `Impl` – the `Base<std::string>` variant and the `Base<char const *>` variant. The former is provided by `Derived`, the latter needs to be implemented. And take all the time you need...I haven't solved it yet either. LOL

Comment: You cannot have both of them called `begin()`. That would be ambiguous.

Comment: I wrote a completely new version of the answer

Comment: @n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m: Ah, so the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770116) I cited only worked because the multiply-inherited member had different parameter types to differentiate them, leading to something that's supported under C++. Lucky them. LOL